# Redirect old Posts URL to new URL

Tags: posts, wp-admin, redirect

This may have a simple answer I'm not aware of, but I'm not familiar with redirects on Wordpress. Here's my question:

I had my default `Posts` routed to `mysite.com/post-name`.

I want to now route the default `Posts` to `mysite.com/blog/post-name`, which I was able to achieve through the Permalinks settings, using the custom structure `/blog/%postname%/`.

The problem now is that the old URLs (`mysite.com/post-name`) don't work (404). How do I redirect all of those old `Posts` to the new `mysite.com/blog/post-name` URL? There are a lot of posts, so I'm looking for a way to do this in bulk.

I've searched for answers, but haven't found anything satisfactory. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solutions to redirect from the old post URL to the new post URL.

1. You can install a plugin "[Safe Redirect Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/)" and set it from the admin panel.
2. You can write some snippet in the `functions.php` file as:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');
function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {
    global $post;
    // this array can contain category names, slugs or even IDs.
    $catArray = ['blog'];
    if (is_single($post->ID) && !has_category($catArray, $post)) {
        $new_url = "http://www.newurl.com/blog/{$post->post_name}/";  
        wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
```

For more details please follow the below link.

https://www.ryadel.com/en/wordpress-redirect-posts-categories-tags-custom-conditions-301-302/amp/

Answer (score 0):

i have changed Custom URL Structure like example.com/post-name to example.com/%category%/%post-name% . there are a lot of pages around 1600 URL, Now I want to redirect my old URL to New URL, How can i do that with rankmath free version.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/265590)